# How to force https in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https, wordpress-theming

I just created a website(www.wealthouseinfo.com) which I installed SSL certificate on but when I accessed the site it was still giving me site unsecured. I then test it on `https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/3b8d24ec-eb16-4627-9494-63e33259694d`to find what the problem might be but the error found was this: `An image with an insecure url of "http://wealthouseinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/bagrd.png" was loaded on line: 1 of https://wealthouseinfo.com/.`
Errors that are reported on line 1 are generally not part of the source code. This error may be caused by an external javascript file which is writing to the page, however we are unable to reliably detect these scripts in our automated test.
Please contact us using the "Need Help?" link below if you need assistance with resolving this error.

I have done everything possible even deleted all the images in the uploads folder but still nothing change.

I am using **newsmax theme**.

Any idea of what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I can handle migrating from http to https. You will need to replace all instances of your http domain w/ https in your database. Also, check your wp-config.php file as well. There are some plugins available to do search and replace on the database. You can Google these. I personally use wp-cli command line tool to do this. I execute "wp search-replace 'http://www.example.com' 'https://www.example.com'. There are flags in wp-cli to do this as a dry run for testing: --dry-run. Be certain to backup your database first. This should take care of your problem and redirect http to https, and ensure that all your local assets are loaded using https. See: http://wp-cli.org/ for more on wp-cli.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the Really Simple SSL plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

In my experience it has handled the kinds of issues you mentioned. I've used it on a WordPress multisite installation as well as regular installations. It's free so it should be worth a try.